# Criando e configurando e-mail na AWS (SES)

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email, amazon-aws, smtp

Possuo uma aplicação em PHP e necessito de um e-mail que servirá apenas para confirmação de cadastros no meu sistema (no-reply@meudominio.com). Estava dando uma olhada no Amazon SES, porém, me surgiram algumas dúvidas:

1. Como criar um e-mail personalizado, do tipo: no-reply@meudominio.com ou contato@meudominio.com?
2. Preciso criar um `Record Set` no Route 53 do tipo `MX` para esse e-mail? Se sim, como configurar corretamente esse `Record Set`?
3. Preciso liberar a porta 25 (SMTP) no meu Security Group ou com a utilização do SES isso não é necessário?
4. No próprio Amazon SES existe a área para verificação de e-mails (`Verify a New Email Address`), enviei apenas para testar uma verificação para o e-mail no-reply@meudominio.com porém como vou poder ter acesso ao conteúdo do e-mail, sendo que o e-mail em questão nem mesmo existe?
5. Estou utilizando a própria função `mail` do PHP, ela funciona corretamente com o SES ou seria necessário implementá-la de uma maneira diferente?

Comment: Respondendo a primeira pergunta, você pode comprar um email na godaddy.com.br se não me engano são 5 reais por mês.

Comment: @Marconi então não é possível criar diretamente através da Amazon?

Comment: Igor com esse email personalizado que você comprará você pode enviar email pelo SES. Creio que virá uma grande resposta. Sua pergunta é muito boa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - A configuração do 'user' é utilizada no envio do tipo SMTP, então voce so precisa do domínio.

2 - A configuração de MX no rota 53 so sera necessario se voce quiser receber email via 'user'@'seu dominio', e nesse caso voce precisa ter um serviço de email externo via SMTP, ou uma aplicação de email SMTP, no seu servidor.

3 - Não precisa liberar a porta.

4 - No caso da verificação do email é exclusivo para o dominio, então voce faz a configuração, após isso voce precisa abrir um chamado na Amazon, solicitando o aumento do serviço SES, que no começo é apenas de teste e paras os emails que voce verificou. Apos a solicitação e aprovação voce pode continuar o processo do SES

5 - A função mail do PHP funciona, mais o melhor é utilizar um pacote SMTP.

Uma observação.:
Quando voce recebe a confirmação da liberação do SES, voce recebe um User e um Password, so utilizar esse user e password no SMTP, salve engano na porta 587, o host vai ser um endereço tbm que a Amazon informa.
Quando voce for criar o email, voce configura os dados: FROM 'email que voce deseja que apareca como remetente', NAME 'o nome que voce deseja'